# Android to iOS calling is not working when my app is killed or in background, (but ios to ios calling is working)

Tags: quickblox, callkit

I have integrated Video and Audio calling feature using QuickBlox. We have a facing issue when the app was in the background, killed/screen locked, The iOS app not getting a call from other platforms.

I have mentioned the current application behaviour

**1.iOS to iOS calls.**

a. when the app is in the foreground, calling functionality works smoothly.

b. when the app is in the background, calling functionality works smoothly.

c. when the app was killed/screen locked, calling functionality works but not smoothly.

**2.android to iOS calls .**

a. when the app is in the foreground, calling functionality works smoothly.

b. when the app is in the background, calling functionality not working.

c. when the app was killed/screen locked, calling functionality not working.

Anybody know how I can achieve this.

Comment: Are you using PushKit and CallKit?

Comment: Yes, I am using PushKit and Callkit.

Comment: So, the incoming call is triggered by a VoIP Push and therefore it can't be any difference between cases 1 and 2 in the iOS app side. If there is really a systematic difference between 1 and 2, the problem must be in the code that generates the push notification (the server?).

Comment: Thanks, As I mentioned its working fine at iOS to iOS end. For Andriod, we have followed the instruction which QuichBlox SDK provided. Both side we have added @"ios_voip" : @"1", @"VOIPCall"  : @"1", required keys. But point 2 b& c condition not worked.